# Not able to add foreign key in POST request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post

I'm getting data into laravel backend with a POST request. When the POST request is triggered, it creates a new row. The issue is that this row has a foreign key. I'm not sure how to generate the foreign key id_deals in the UserController. The id_deals value doesn't come from POST request.

**laravel migration with id_deals as foreign key**

```
    {
       Schema::create('places', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('staff_id')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('place_id'); 
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_deals');
            $table->string('address')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('photo_places')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('activities_associated')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('approved')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('requested_by_staff')->nullable(); 
            //fk id
            $table->foreign('id_deals')->references('id')->on('deals');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function createPlace(Request $request){
        
        Log::debug($request);
        $token =  preg_split('/\s+/', $request->header('Authorization'));
        

        $newPlace = new Place();
        $newPlace->place_id = $request->autocomplete;
        $newPlace->requested_by_staff = $request->requested_by_staff;
        $newPlace->activities_associated = $request->activities_associated;
        $newPlace->save();

        return response()->json($request, 200);
```

Comment: `deals` hasMany `places`?

Comment: deal belongs to one place!

Comment: Then `places` is the parent of `deals` table? If so then you need to create foreign key on `deals` table, not `places` table

Comment: If deal belongs to one place then the place id should be in deal table not reverse

Comment: Thank you everyone. The problem has been fixed!